# edubuntu-artwork

Tags: 18.04

I'm getting "installed edubuntu-artwork package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127" and have tried update, upgrade, autoremove, synaptic fix broken packages, and grub repair from a live cd start. What is the answer? Please advise.

Comment: Grub repair does not fix packaging problems. Please add full output of `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to the question.

Comment: So it's saying that the [script it runs](https://gist.github.com/pbhj/3b0ba2aa75b7d401c6c8ec569a4f19df) after you've removed that package is giving an error. I'd try to `sudo apt install edubuntu-artwork` and then `sudo apt purge ...` the same package, could be the original script was corrupted somehow. Or, I'd use `sudo dpkg --purge edubuntu-artwork`, after which you might need to `sudo apt -f install`. FWIW I just installed and removed v15.12.1 with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.  Looks to me that the edubuntu-artwork package is missing a dependency on `gconf-defaults-service` as it calls `update-gconf-defaults` from the post-install and post-remove package scripts at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/edubuntu-artwork.postinst` & `.postrm` .

What I did:

1. Commented out the calls to `update-gconf-defaults` in the `postinst` and `postrm` package scripts under `/var/lib/dpkg/info`
2. `sudo dpkg --configure edubuntu-artwork`

   This ran the post-install script successfully and updated the package status to 'installed'
3. `sudo apt install gconf-defaults-service`
4. `sudo apt-get remove --purge edubuntu-artwork`

Presumably if you now re-install it, it will install properly.

I will also email edubuntu-devel@lists.ubuntu.com about it. I will let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and spent 2 hours trying to remove it using command after command, yet still received the "Exit Status (127)" error.  It blocked further updates coming through Synaptic and APT, and nearly resulted in clumps of hair being torn from my head!!

After a bit of digging around I found entries to `edubuntu-artwork` here `/var/lib/dpkg`.

The files were `edubuntu-artwork.list` , `edubuntu-artwork.md5sums` , `edubuntu-artwork.postinst` , `edubuntu-artwork.postrm` , `edubuntu-artwork.preinst` & `edubuntu-artwork.prerm`.

I took admin control of the folder & changed their ownership properties to delete each of the above files permanently - I then uninstalled `Synaptic Package Manager` (reinstalling after a restart).

After the restart & reinstallation, In Terminal, I ran through the `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get update` & `sudo apt-get autoremove` commands again. ensuring I also used the `--purge  & -f flags` to force removal of any stuck package.

APT ran through the motions installing / auto-removing as normal, also deleting any installed dependencies that ed-ubuntu-artwork relied on & I no longer received the `1 Partial or Not Installed` warning message, nor the error message stating `Error (127)`.

Re-examining Synaptic, I also found that the edubuntu-artwork was no longer marked Broken or Installed, but back in the Recommended Packages Section.

I ran through the scenario again, attempting a fresh reinstall & still came across this issue.

Needless to say this is one "Recommended Package" I DO NOT RECOMMEND as it appears to be a corrupted package by the developers which causes no end of issues..

Answer (score 0):

i found any file named 'edubuntu-artwork' using wildcard *

open location, open location in terminal, `rm *u-art*`

repeat for other locations

run synaptic (i had already tried to remove it so it was marked for removal)
click apply

package now removed

no error